# Building lib_mysqludf_stem on Kubuntu 64bit - configure problems

Tags: mysql, linux, configure, ubuntu

I'm trying to build lib_mysqludf_stem from https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_stem
on Kubuntu 14.04 64bit and ran into troubles while doing configure\make steps.

The config output looks like that: http://pastebin.com/pyY6UrX5

I especially worried about these lines:

> checking for MySQL libraries... awk: line 1: syntax error at or near ==
>
> ./configure: line 15370: test: ==: unary operator expected yes
>
> checking for mysqlbin... ./configure: line 15508: MYSQLBIN_PATH: command not found

make doesn't work after that too: can't execute stat for  «.deps/lib_mysqludf_stem_la-lib_mysqludf_stem.Tpo» - there is no such file.

Does anyone have some experience of building this tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I haven't found any solution but the lib author confirmed this problem and promised to fix it. The discussion is here: https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_stem/issues/2
So, I suppose I just need to wait for a while.